# MongoDB geoNear Aggregation - Order of Operations

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, geospatial

I have a simple MongoDo Aggregation query:

```
{
    "$geoNear": {
        "near": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
                -73.982,
                40.7685
            ]
        },
        "spherical": "true",
        "distanceField": "d",
        "limit": 100000,
        "maxDistance": 8046.7,
        "query": {
            "ipv": 1
        }
    }
},
{
    "$sort": {
        "created_at": -1
    }
},
{
    "$limit": 5
}
```

My simple question is along the lines of query order of operations. Does the query scan ALL documents for a matching coords, then from that data set, matches ipv: 1, then sorted by created_at, then limit 5?

If so - this isn't happening. I have a to place a "limit" field, or it will only scan back 100 of the last records, match the geo coords, then do the order of operations.

Is there a way to have MongoDB scan ALL records for the matching GPS Coords, then perform the matching?

Answer (score 13):

Here's how $geoNear works: It gets a cursor to documents whose coordinates satisfy the *maxDistance* requirement. It then iterates over the cursor and for each document checks if it matches the *query* requirement. If it doesn't, it skips it and moves to the next document. It does this until it finds *limit*-many documents or the end of the cursor. Note that this is the *limit* argument to the $geoNear command, not the $limit operation specified later in the aggregation pipeline.

The default *limit* is 100, so if you don't specify *limit* you are getting the first 100 documents that match *query* and whose coordinates satisfy *maxDistance*, sorting those 100 documents by created_at, and then taking the first 5. When you specify *limit*:100000, you are getting the first 100000 documents that match *query* and whose coordinates satisfy *maxDistance*, sorting those 100000 documents by created_at, and then taking the first 5.

If you are trying to get the 5 nearest documents to your Point, and then sort those 5 documents by created_at, you should set the $geoNear *limit* to 5 and remove the $limit operation from the pipeline altogether. If you want to scan ALL documents for matching coordinates, sort the resulting documents by created_at, and then get the first 5, you should set the $geoNear *limit* to a value larger than the size of the collection, and leave the rest as you have it. Hope that helps.